# Android| Java Notifications not appearing in API 25 and lower

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a firebase push notifications that sends text messages. My notifications appear in API 26 onward, but on APIs lower, (currently testing with API 22) and the messages are successfully sent, but they dont appear on the (API 22) device. What could be the problem?

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        createNotificationChannel();
        String messageTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String messageBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
        String dataMessage = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
        String dataFrom = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        Intent intent = new Intent(click_action);
        intent.putExtra("message", dataMessage);
        intent.putExtra("from_user_id", dataFrom);
        PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(resultIntent);
        int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, builder.build());
    }


    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Personal Notifications";
            String desc = "Include all the personal notifications";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id), name, importance);
            notificationChannel.setDescription(desc);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }

}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have situation, when notification appears in status bar, but a floating window not popping up, you should add in your NotificationCompat.Builder

```
.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
```

because such notifications are called a heads-up notifications and it should have high priority and use ringtones or vibrations on devices running Android 7.1 (API level 25) and lower

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have targeted Oreo and above in your createNotificationsChannel.

Exact place you target oreo and above is:

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)`

The reason why this has happened will be because of the code listed below since it was added in API level 26. You will need to find an alternative version for lower levels.

`notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);`

Comment: Lower than API 26, you don't need a notification channel so that code is skipped completely though. I'm using the code from here https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Answer (score 0):

I had this a while ago. Keep your `createNotificationChannel()` method in your main class. However, I suggest creating a different class with a static method (to create your notification) then just call it in the `FirebaseMessagingService` class. Try this:

```
public class NotificationHelper {
    public static void displayNotification(Context context,String title,String body){
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,CHANNELID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat =  NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        managerCompat.notify(1,mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Then in your `FMService` class, just call the static method after your notification channel like so:

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        createNotificationChannel();
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            String messageTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String messageBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            NotificationHelper.displayNotification(getApplicationContext(),messageTitle,messageBody);
        }
```

You should be fine.